# Blog link pointing to mobile edition?

Tags: bug, status-norepro

The blog link at the bottom of stackoverflow takes me to the mobile version of the blog despite browsing from desktop:

[image]

[image]

Update: Also the link to "Exit the mobile edition" doesn't do anything. Seems to just refresh the page.

Comment: Where did the comments go? Anyway, after removing that parameter from the URL like someone here said, I now get the desktop version, and there doesn't seem to be a way to go to the mobile version now. cc @Oded

Comment: @Stijn Comments seem to have randomly disappeared. Cool, just tried it and works for me now.

Comment: Was there ever a way, @Stijn? I don't recall ever seeing a mobile version of the blogs.

Comment: @Oded I have no idea, I just clicked on the blog link in the footer and saw the same as in OP's screenshot. Odd.

Comment: I think they were doing a update, at least now there's a **|** between `add comment` and `show X more comments`, and that caused this bug.